# Identify module at runtime

Tags: java, maven

I have a multimodule maven project. One module has several dependencies on other modules in the maven project. I'd like to inspect which top-level module each class is from at run time - is there any way to do this with reflection?

For Example:

```
com.company:running-module:jar:1.0.0
 +- com.company:top-level-module-1:jar:1.0.0:compile
 |  \- com.company:low-level-module-1:jar:1.0.0:compile
 |     \- ClassOfInterest.java
 +- com.company:top-level-module-2:jar:1.0.0:compile
 |  \- com.company:low-level-module-1:jar:1.0.0:compile
 |     \- ClassOfInterest.java
 \- com.company:top-level-module-3:jar:1.0.0:compile
    \- com.company:low-level-module-2:jar:1.0.0:compile
       \- OtherClassOfInterest.java
```

Inspecting `ClassOfInterest` would return `top-level-module-1` and `top-level-module-2` while inspecting `OtherClassOfInterest` would return `top-level-module-3.

Comment: Why do you need this information? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a way to do it, it would be very hacky.

Modify each module to have different top level package and then you can easily do it with reflection by inspecting full class name.